# Партиционирование mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с полями 
name | position(int 11)

И так получилось, что люди запрашивают в основном только с позицией ниже 100.
Ну типа первые 100 лучших постов.
От 100 уже редко до 500, и от 500 уже не запрашивают почти никогда.

Хочу сделать партиционирование таблицы как раз по таким интервалам.

От 1 до 100, от 101 до 500 и от 501 до MAXVALUE

Вопрос заключается в том, что теоретически, рейтинг у статьи может измениться, и если она была месяц назад с рейтингом 400, может стать 50.

В данном случае применимо ли партиционирование? И как его реализовать с учетом этих условий

Comment: А самого обыкновенного индекса не хватает что ли?

Comment: А вообще существования поля position на первый взгляд странно: если оно зависит только от рейтинга, то логичнее просто по рейтингу и сортировать при выборке (опять же с индексом)

Comment: @andreymal Я утрировал количество записей. На самом деле интервал на много больше.

Comment: @andreymal система сделана так, что позиция хоть и зависит от рейтинга, но обновляется раз в сутки

Comment: Партиционирование как-то не кажется на такой задаче разумным... полностью согласен с **andreymal** - индекса более чем достаточно. Особенно если индекс кластерный... жаль, в InnoDB кластерный - это всегда первичный.

Comment: Если люди действительно очень часто запрашивают 100 первых постов, их можно кэшировать.